# How to refresh a specific layout in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

I want to refresh a part of layout on the basis of a combobox. But whenever I try to overwrite a layout it gives following error.

```
QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on QFrame "", which already has a layout
```

Thank You for your time and concern. 
I am a newbie to GUI design so it would be marvelous if you tell some good tutorial site to hand on PyQt

Comment: What do you mean with "refresh"? If your goal is to hide and show elements then this has nothing to do with a Layout. The Layout is used only to position widgets with respect to each other. If you want to show or hide them you can call the .show() and .hide() methods on each widget (you can add them all, hide the ones you do not need and upon some events, like button pressed, hide the ones you don't want to display and show some other widgets)

Comment: I want to remove and add new widget into the layout.

Comment: Then you can add all the widgets to the layout, and hide the ones you do not want to show. Then, as I wrote in the first answer, change the visibility of the widgets when some event occur.

Comment: this means it is not possible to redo the layout once it is showed.

Comment: You can add and remove widgets, but if the widget you are adding requires some computation time you'd probably experience some delay in the user interface. I usually create all the widgets before showing my window so if the process takes some time I can display a progress bar or something like that

Comment: thanks alot. i did the same to build all and hiding the redundant one